# Matlab fails to delete temporary storage folder

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, temporary-files

I create a `parpool` object in the following way:

```
c = parcluster(); 
c.JobStorageLocation = storage_folder;
p = gcp('nocreate'); % If no pool, do not create new one yet.
if isempty(p)
    parpool(c, num_cores); % creates parallel pool
elseif p.NumWorkers ~= num_cores
    delete(p); % deletes existing one
    parpool(c, num_cores); % creates parallel pool
end
```

I tried to delete the folder `storage_folder` at the end of my script by doing

```
rmdir(storage_folder, 's');
```

but I get the following error:

```
Warning: Error occurred while executing the listener callback for event
ObjectBeingDestroyed defined for class parallel.settings.Profile:
Invalid or deleted object.

Error in parallel.Cluster/handleProfileDeleted (line 439)
            obj.ProfileObject = parallel.settings.Profile.empty();

Error in parallel.Cluster>@(~,~)obj.handleProfileDeleted() (line 434)
                    @(~, ~) obj.handleProfileDeleted() );
```

Any advice on why it happens and how to solve it would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot delete the folder when it’s still being used, and the callback is probably being called when the folder is still being used. Maybe there’s a different event that is triggered after those objects have been deleted?

Comment: Doesn’t MATLAB clean up after itself when it closes down?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I don't know about MATLAB cleaning up after itself (you have a reference for that?), but I'm also wondering about whether the folder was still being used. To check, I commented out the line `rmdir(storage_folder, 's');`, but the rest is the same. I get the same error as above, so your hunch about another event interfering seems correct... Any suggestions on how to check where exactly the error is occuring?